# Wordpress Plugin development

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin.

In this plugin I am trying to get the hostname of the server.

Is this possible?

I see tags/filters like:

- get_home_url
- get_site_url
- home_url
- get_page_link

But they do not seem to work in plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the PHP $_SERVER predefined variable rather than worry about whether a WP function is available or not.

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

will give you something like: www.example.com

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. Its so difficult to find what your looking for in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use bloginfo('url'); wich gets the baseurl
or are you looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use these core functions on **init** Hook. Plugins always have core functions available/accessible.